# How to calculate a route for walking or driving direction

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am not sure if there is a difference between calculating a walking and driving direction. say, I want to go from point A to point B by walking. Do I use the normal route calculation in BingMap? Is the normal Route calculation for driving only?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`BingMapsDirectionTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.bingmapsdirectionstask%28v=vs.92%29) only allows start and end points to be specified at present - your end user can choose to change the directions given to them, to be walking or driving.

Comment: I guess the route calculation is based on driving. For normal shopping route like from Mall A to mall B, we can refer to the route calculation and make adjustment. It will be nice if I know which direction I face when I got my current GPS with a rotating arrow.

Comment: The location sensor can give you a heading based on movement, and the compass can give you a heading, assuming no electromagnetic interference (personally, I would consider the compass a vague indication of a bearing, rather than something you could rely on)

Comment: @RS : Thanks for the advice on the accuracy of the compass. I will follow the trusted way like BingMapDirectiontask since I need 2 pionts. Have not tried out Bing Geocode an address. Would appreciate if you can point me a sample code. this will help me. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx for geocoding addresses via Bing.